# Propagate value from nested class to base class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a TensorFlow based project where the goal is to be very abstract in implementation.

I have reached a problem however with adding GoogleNet to my project.
As opposed to most other networks I have implemented thus far (alexnet, vggnet, etc), GoogleNet is different in that it uses an "Auxiliary" classifier at two points in the network. This means that rather than being a straight sequential pass through the network, I need to diverge and remember data at these "Auxiliary" points for use later.

The problem arises because I use the class `tf.keras.Sequential` specifically because it makes the project much easier to read and debug. I would really prefer to keep using this class for those reasons, however its behaviour basically prevents the "Auxiliary" classifier from doing what it needs to do. This is because the output of a given layer wrapped in `tf.keras.Sequential` is passed as the input to the following wrapped layer.

Since "Auxiliary" is a class in my implementation, this means I can only return one item from its call function at a time, as to not break `Sequential`. And since it is a diverging classifier, I currently return its unaltered input, as to not mess with the following layers. Thus it currently performs the necessary calculations, but I have no where to store the output.

I have thought about this problem for a while, and came up with several solutions that involve restructuring my code, such as putting everything in one file, removing `tf.keras.Sequential`, or ignoring the "Auxiliary" altogether since it works without it, but I have not been able to figure out a way to keep my structure and perform this variable update.

The current structure of the project is as follows:

```
cnn.py
______________________________
from models.py import googlenet
class CNN() -> calls function googlenet() inside __init__()

    models.py
    _______________________________
    from layers.py import Auxiliary
    def googlenet() -> invokes class Auxiliary()

        layers.py
        ________________
        class Auxiliary() -> performs calculations
                          -> needs to propagate value to CNN() class
                          -> has to return unaltered input
```

I have tried every way I could think of to import "CNN" into "Auxiliary", each causing an import error. I have tried to pass the "CNN" class instance itself to the "Auxiliary" class to no avail, since I am passing the class inside the constructor of said class. And I have tried to make the "Auxiliary" class inherit from the "CNN" class, even though that doesn't make sense from a design perspective.

So how do I propagate a result from one class to another, which are both in separate files, without using a return statement or creating a circular dependency?